# Having trouble calling an element from a terraform nested map object

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to create a terraform for Azure Data Collection rule. Below is my variable declaration:

```
 variable "data_collection_rules" {
  type = map(object({
    location            = string
    name                = string
    resource_group_name = string
    data_flow = map(object({
      destinations = list(string)
      streams = list(string)
      built_in_transform = string
      output_stream = string
      transform_kql = string
    }))
    destinations = object({
      enable_azure_monitor_metrics = bool
      azure_monitor_metrics = object({
        name = string
      })
      enable_log_analytics = bool
      log_analytics = map(object({
        name = string
        log_analytics_workspace_variable_name = string
      }))
      enable_storage_blob = bool
      storage_blob = map(object({
        container_name = string
        name = string
        storage_account_variable_name = string
      }))
    })
  }))
}

variable "log_analytics_workspace_ids" {
  type = map(string)
}

variable "storage_account_ids" {
  type = map(string)
}
```

Below is my module declaration:

```
resource "azurerm_monitor_data_collection_rule" "data_collection_rule" {
    for_each = var.data_collection_rules
    location = each.value["location"]
    name = each.value["name"]
    resource_group_name = each.value["resource_group_name"]
    dynamic "data_flow" {
      for_each = each.value["data_flow"]
      content {
        destinations = data_flow.value["destinations"]
        streams = data_flow.value["streams"]
        built_in_transform = data_flow.value["built_in_transform"]
        output_stream = data_flow.value["output_stream"]
        transform_kql = data_flow.value["transform_kql"]
      }
    }
    destinations {
      dynamic "azure_monitor_metrics" {
         for_each = each.value.destinations["enable_azure_monitor_metrics"]  == true ? [1] : []
         content {
          name = each.value.destinations.azure_monitor_metrics["name"]
         }       
      }
      dynamic "log_analytics" {
         for_each = each.value.destinations["enable_log_analytics"]  == true ? [1] : []
         content {
          name = each.value.destinations.log_analytics["name"]
          workspace_resource_id = lookup(var.log_analytics_workspace_ids, each.value.destinations.log_analytics["log_analytics_workspace_variable_name"], null)
         } 
      }
      dynamic "storage_blob" {
        for_each = each.value.destinations["enable_storage_blob"]  == true ? [1] : []
        content {
          container_name = each.value.destinations.storage_blob["container_name"]
          name = each.value.destinations.storage_blob["name"]
          storage_account_id = lookup(var.storage_account_ids, each.value.destinations.storage_blob["storage_account_variable_name"], null)
         } 
      }
    }
}
```

I am passing the below value to it, where log_analytics_workspace_variable_name and storage_account_variable_name are the keys of map variables I used for creating a log anytics  workspace and a storage account :

```
data_collection_rules = {
  data_collection_rule1 = {             
    location            = "canadacentral"  
    name                = "data_collection_rule1"   
    resource_group_name = "test-rg" 
    data_flow = {
      data_flow1 ={
        destinations = ["data-collection-destination-monitoring-matrics"] 
        streams = ["Microsoft-InsightsMetrics"] 
        built_in_transform = null 
        output_stream = null 
        transform_kql = null 
      },
      data_flow2 ={
        destinations = ["data-collection-destination-log-analytics-1"] 
        streams = ["Microsoft-Perf"] 
        built_in_transform = null 
        output_stream = null 
        transform_kql = null 
      },
      data_flow3 ={
        destinations = ["data-collection-destination-storage_blob"] 
        streams = ["Microsoft-Syslog"] 
        built_in_transform = null 
        output_stream = null 
        transform_kql = null 
      }
    }
      destinations = {
        enable_azure_monitor_metrics = true 
        azure_monitor_metrics = {
          name = "data-collection-destination-monitoring-matrics" 
        }
        enable_log_analytics = true             
        log_analytics = {
          log_analytics_1 = {
            name = "data-collection-destination-log-analytics-1" 
            log_analytics_workspace_variable_name = "log_analytics_workspace1"  
          }
        }
        enable_storage_blob = true 
        storage_blob = {
          storage_blob1 = {
            container_name = "sa-container1" 
            name = "data-collection-destination-storage_blob" 
            storage_account_variable_name = "sa1" 
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am getting the below error when I run terraform plan:
[image]

I am getting the same error for all elements inside "log_analytics" and "storage_blob" destinations.

I understand that the way I am calling the elements is causing the issue but I can't quite figure out how I can resolve this.

Comment: I have tried using "each.value.destinations.log_analytics.name" it also gives me the same error

Answer (score 0):

This is what is happening right now

```
data_collection_rule1 = {      #  each.value  
  destinations = {             #  each.value.destinations
    log_analytics = {          #  each.value.destinations.log_analytics
      log_analytics_1 = {      #  each.value.destinations.log_analytics["name"]  <- error
        name = "data-collection-destination-log-analytics-1" 
        log_analytics_workspace_variable_name = "log_analytics_workspace1"  
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Since log_analytics is a map you need to specify the key of the object which you want to access.
This should return "data-collection-destination-log-analytics-1"

```
each.value.destinations.log_analytics.log_analytics_1.name
```

It is not clear in your question, but I suspect what you actually want is to *dynamically* access each object in the log_analytics map.
To do that you first need to change how you iterate in the dynamic block, because right now you can only have 0 or 1 of that object.

```
dynamic "log_analytics" {
  # If enable_log_analytics is true you want to process every block specified
  for_each = each.value.destinations.enable_log_analytics  == true ? each.value.destinations.log_analytics : {}
  content {
    # When using a dynamic block you get an iterator with the same name as the block, it work the same as your regular each.
    name = log_analytics.value.name
    workspace_resource_id = lookup(var.log_analytics_workspace_ids, log_analytics.value.log_analytics.log_analytics_workspace_variable_name, null)
  } 
}
```